# Run Git as Apache on remote server

Tags: apache-2.2, git, file-permissions

I’m trying to set up a workflow where my code base is version-controlled under Git, and then deployed to a live server over SSH.

I wrote a simple shell script that I run from my machine that opens an SSH connection and then executes `git pull` on the remote server. However, because this is being ran under `root` (don’t ask) all files and folders that are then created/updated by Git are given the user/group of `root` too, instead of `apache`.

How do re-assign `apache` as the user/group of these files/folders? Do I need to alter my workflow, or could I just run `chown` and `chgrp` after I’ve pulled from Git? Ideally, I’d like to just fix where I’d rather treat the problem though rather than treating the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

You'ld better use another user than root. Anyway, use `su -c` or `sudo` to run `git pull` with the correct username

Comment: I know, but it’s a client’s server and that’s the only login they’ve given me. How do I use `su -c`/`sudo` to run `git pull` as `apache`?

Comment: They gave you root access, so in effect it is NOT the only login the gave you.  They gave you the keys to the kingdom.  So now you can set it up correctly.

Comment: So what is the correct steps to get Git to pull on the remote server, but not then assign everything it does the user/group of `root`?

Comment: You might look at this setup.  http://serverfault.com/a/234442/144062